# How can I get an swf file to play automatically?

Tags: asp.net, flash, actionscript, macromedia

I have been given the task of converting a macromedia application to a web app. It seems the application begins with the shell.swf once the exe is started. I have experimented with embedding the project's different swf files, and one thing I've figured out is that entire project works without the exe if the the shell.swf is somehow started. I've been opening and running the shell.swf with CS5.5 flash professional. *I do not have the source project.

This leads to my question. All of the swf files of this application autorun when embedded into an aspx, except the shell.swf, which appears to be the directing file of the application. **How can I get this shell.swf to autorun from an aspx load event?** I pretty much need to mimic the Flash Professional's play button. This is an interactive application to educate young people about the Buffalo river, and it is somewhat robust. I am almost certain that once I can get the shell.swf running on a webpage, the entire app will run it's course.

I have been working with AspNetFlash, but I have not been able to achieve the desired effect. I need to get this running so the client can utilize the program over the next few months while I am re-writing the application to store user interactive data. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SWF Files play automatically, it just depends on the content.From what im understanding the "exe" file just exucutes, i have done this myself with C#. So im presuming if you embed the shell SWF on a html page it will play the other content, just make sure all the content is in the same order as the original for example, the locations of other SWF's in their folder directories.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have all of the files in the original directory order, but the shell.swf does not autoplay. But if I open the shell.swf in Adobe Flash Professional and click controls->play, the whole application will function. I need a way to mimic this play function.

Comment: the reason its not autoplaying is the shell.SWF is preventing it or the second movie has a stop function on the time line, to play this is would ignore the shell.swf and load the other movie into a blank SWF and target it to play

Comment: I'll try that. Thanks. My only concern is most of the application's logic looks to be programmed in the shell.swf.